# converting KaTeX to MathJax

Tags: mathjax, katex

Is there currently any way in javascript to convert a KaTeX formular to MathJax, I want to support exporting to Anki which just works with MathJax.
If not, is there a table which shows which commands of KaTeX are not supported in MathJax, I can't seem to find one.
I just need the conversion from KaTeX to MathJax, not the other way around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround might be the new addon for anki that supports katex.  I'm not ready to use it yet (there appears to be some bugs with line-breaking.  See comments on the link).

https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/1087328706

I have the same use case as you. I write markdown and katex in vscode (with Markdown+Math extension), and export to anki (using ankdown - slightly modified).

I find that sometimes mathjax causes problems - for example with tags.

Comment: fun thing you shared it here because thats the addon I created after asking this question, thanks for the free promotion :D I'll look into the bugs, didn't see your comment on anki yet because I don't get emails if someone comments there

Comment: So I tracked down one error in the $$...$$ environment where & is converted to &amp; by anki which you can fix by adding `str = str.replace(/&amp;/g, "&");` but I haven't yet found the bug you mentioned in the comment, could you please provide an example where you get that error?

Comment: Try pasting this gist into a card https://gist.github.com/universemaster/8d5a7194599a517d38faa4f8bf20620b

Comment: Ahh I think the reason for that is not the addon but anki in combination with vs code, this is an error I experienced as well, I think the reason for that is that vscode adds colors to the text and if you copy it directly into anki the colors are then added by adding `<span>` tags. If you copy it into a text editor and then into anki the example works. I think adding the code you used in the comment could therefor break some other cases together with VSCode so as a workaround just copy it into a text file and from there into anki!

Comment: @PaulMüller You are correct that pasting text in the anki editor from elsewhere can cause `<span>` elements. However, this occurs regardless of where the text is pasted *from*.  If I paste directly into anki from with the *edit HTML* menu, then I do not get `<span>` elements. I agree, that this isn't a problem with your addon!

Comment: Okay I've just noticed that I got the `span` regex anyways in the Cloze card type and it worked till now, you're probably right, I'll add the regex to the addon, thank alot!